# Scatter plot with different groups and marginal histograms for each group

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, scatter-plot

I already have a scatter plot with different groups of elements and histograms on the margins, but they are linked to the whole data, not to the individual groups:

[image: Example of my current plot]

I'd like to have 2 histograms, one for each group of elements. How do I do that?
Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

data= pd.read_csv("data.csv")
x=data['Fe']
y=data['V']
z=data['Discovery']

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# definitions for the axes
left, width = 0.1, 0.7
bottom, height = 0.1, 0.7
spacing = 0.05


rect_scatter = [left, bottom, width, height]
rect_histx = [left, bottom + height + spacing, width, 0.2]
rect_histy = [left + width + spacing, bottom, 0.2, height]

# start with a rectangular Figure
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))


ax_scatter = plt.axes(rect_scatter)
ax_scatter.tick_params(direction='in', top=True, right=True)
ax_histx = plt.axes(rect_histx)
ax_histx.tick_params(direction='in', labelbottom=True)
ax_histy = plt.axes(rect_histy)
ax_histy.tick_params(direction='in', labelleft=False)

# the function that separates the dots in different classes:
classes = np.zeros( len(x) )
classes[(z == 'Transit')] = 1
classes[(z == 'Radial Velocity')] = 2


# create color map:
colors = ['purple', 'orange']
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom', colors, N=len(colors))

# the scatter plot:
scatter = ax_scatter.scatter(x, y, c=classes, s=10, cmap=cm, alpha=0.6)
lines, labels = scatter.legend_elements()

# legend with custom labels
labels = [r'Transit', r'Radial Velocity']
legend = ax_scatter.legend(lines, labels,
                    loc="upper left", title="Planetary Discovery Method")
ax_scatter.add_artist(legend)

# now determine nice limits by hand:
binwidth = 0.1
ax_scatter.set_xlim((-1, 0.7))
ax_scatter.set_ylim((-0.9, 0.9))

#histogram
weights = np.ones_like(x)/(len(x))
weights2 = np.ones_like(y)/(len(y))
ax_histx.hist(x, bins=bins, weights=weights, color='chartreuse')
ax_histy.hist(y, bins=bins, weights=weights, orientation='horizontal', color='darkmagenta')


ax_histx.set_xlim(ax_scatter.get_xlim())
ax_histy.set_ylim(ax_scatter.get_ylim())

#labeling
ax_scatter.set_xlabel('[Fe/H]')
ax_scatter.set_ylabel('[V/H]')
ax_histy.set_xlabel('Relative Dist.')
ax_histx.set_ylabel('Relative Dist.')
plt.show()
```

I'll add an example of a plot I'm trying to reach:

[image: Example of intended graphic]

Comment: You really shouldn't try to construct such a plot "manually", when Seaborn has its [`sns.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) which creates this out-of-the-box. Once created, you can still customize that jointplot via matplotlib.

Comment: Well, you are right. I was overcomplicating things. Thanks!